# Xcode - CGContext - Eraser painting app "transparant" eraser for background

Tags: xcode, cgcontext

I have a small question.

I am making a painting/drawing app for the iPhone. In my app you can draw on backgrounds and photo's. But i can't find the solution for a eraser. Because most of the eraser samples are white colored paint. So on a non-white background it is just making white "lines". Any solutions for a (sort of) transparant eraser that will erase only draw "lines" and not the background?

Thnx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing using a blend mode of kCGBlendModeNormal with a white coloured paint, you will want to draw using a kCGBlendModeDestinationOut when the eraser is on. (This assumes the background is in a layer behind the drawing layer.)

For example:

```
<pre>
if (eraser == TRUE) // Erase to show background
{
   CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeDestinationOut);
}
else // Draw with color
{
   CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);
}
</pre>
```

You might also like to view this CGBlendMode reference that shows the effect of different blend types including explanations, originally posted at: http://ericasadun.com/CookbookTest/Blending.pdf

Alternative link to document: http://www.docdroid.net/xt0b/blending-kcgblendmode.pdf.html